# my spring boot app container can't connect to my postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to dockerize my spring boot app that uses postgresql  so I first run
*./mvnw clean package -DskipTests*
after I did
*cp target/docker-spring-boot-postgres-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar src/main/docker*

here's my code

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'demo:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgreTest
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=B123456789
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=B123456789
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

**application.props**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgreTest?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=B123456789
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

but i keep getting the same error

> 2021-07-16 15:25:31.986  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
> app    |
> app    | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to db:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP
> connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a nice question! At first glance at your config, I can't see anything that stands out as outright wrong. I believe it's possible that you are trying to connect to your `db` before `postgres` is fully started.

## Waiting for your postgres process to start (rather than simply your container)

Provided that's the problem, you are most likely advised to not use a raw `depends_on` (which will just wait till the `container` itself is started, but rather a `depends_on` with a condition and a `healthcheck`.

With that approach you make sure you check whether `postgres` is **really** started, not just the container, but the database itself. I.e you can do something like:

```
// ...
services:
  postgres:
    // ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 1s    

  app:
    //... do your springboot app stuff here
    depends_on: 
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

## EDIT: Making sure the database underneath actually exists

You mentioned in your comment that now you get another error saying it can't find your database. That's most likely because while the `postgres` process itself is started, the **database your jdbc connection string** refers to is not created.

By default, `postgres` databases you get out of the box are:

- `template0`
- `template1`
- `postgres`

See also this [link](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-list-databases-and-tables-in-postgresql-using-psql/#:%7E:text=Most%20Postgres%20servers%20have%20three,have%20created%20any%20other%20databases.) for more information.

Since your `jdbc` string connects/expects to connect to another database: `jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgreTest`, you most likely need to create that database beforehand.

### How to create the `postgreTest` database beforehand?

Well, there are multiple ways:

- **more spring-y/java-y** approach: using a raw jdbc connection in your spring context and doing create database statements before the rest of your context starts up
- more `docker-y`: Make sure your container has the database you need upon startup. This is the one I'd describe how to do below.

The postgres-docker container [supports multiple properties](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), in addition to:

```
POSTGRES_USER=xyz
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxx
```

you can also override the default database name created (which is `postgres`, if your user is also `postgres`) by utilizing the `POSTGRES_DB` property. The documentation reads:

> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of `POSTGRES_USER` will be used

Basically, you'd do something like:

```
  db:
    image: 'postgres:alpine'
    container_name: db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 1s 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=B123456789
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgreTest
```

Which would end up creating your database, waiting for it to fully start (due to the healthcheck), and then also create the `postgresTest` database, and only then be considered healthy. Then your spring app would have its all dependencies and would be ready to start.

## Docker-compose spec version

**Note**: btw, I notice you use `version 2` of the compose specification, I'd switch to [latest 3,](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) as 2 (and 1) are very clunky and often don't allow for some possibilities which are fairly easy to achieve in the new spec version.

Comment: i did what you suggested but now i get another error which states my db can't be found

Comment: Did you create a database named postgreTest?  The capitalization could be problematic.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Consider accepting my answer so others stumbling upon the same problem can resolve it quicker.